# Android Studio back button activity

Tags: java

I've been trying to find out the back navigation button to lead to another activity.

Every time when I pressed the back button, it goes to the previous activity which is not what I want. I would like to set the back button that goes to another activity I want, instead of previous one.

For example, I have Activity 1, 2 and 3. I was in Activity 2 and just moved to Activity 3. But when I press the back button, it goes automatically to the previous activity which is Activity 2. I want to make it to Activity 1 and not Activity 2. Can anyone suggest me a solution please?

Comment: When you open Activity3 from Activity2, add finish(); after the Intent.
Else, override the method onBackPressed() in Activity3

Answer (score 0):

You can make the button to go to a specific activity, instead of having the default behavior that you described.
It can be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);

    intent.putExtra("variable", information); //this is optional, but can be useful if you need to send a specific info to the next activity
                                            
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but the problem still remains. This is how my code looks like. I have 2 buttons in Activity 2 and 3, that lead to the previous or next Activity. But when I pressed the Back button in Activity 3, it still goes to Activity 2 and not 1.

Comment: Also, when I typed parliamonar.this it underlined the word with red color so I had to do it this way: Intent back = new Intent((Context) parliamonar, federalparliamentary.class);

Comment: The example that I provided was just to show you how you can navigate between activities and I was hoping you can adjust it to your problem, but I should've specified that. So, let's assume you're now in Activity 3 (federalpaliamentary) and you want to go to Activity 1 when the button is clicked( you didn't specified how the Activity1 is called so let's assume you named it "Activity1").
Now, in order to do so, you need to add the onClick(...) method into Activity3 (federalpariamentary) and change the intent to: Intent intent = new Intent(federalparliamentary.this, Activity1.class);

Comment: I added onClick method in federalpariamentary, but it still didn't fix the problem. I tried several ways to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Activity 2 is parliamonar, and Activity 3 is federalparliamentary. I replaced parliamonar with Activity 1, but it still didn't solve the problem.

public class federalparliamentary extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button federal;
private Object parliamonar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_federalparliamentary);

    federal = findViewById(R.id.back160);

    federal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent reserve = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), parliamonar.class);
            startActivity(reserve);
        }
    });

    federal = findViewById(R.id.next164);

    federal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent reserve = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sar.class);
            startActivity(reserve);
        }
    });



}

public void onClick(View V) {

    Intent back = new Intent((Context) parliamonar, federalparliamentary.class);

    startActivity(back);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public class federalparliamentary extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button federal;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_federalparliamentary);

    federal = findViewById(R.id.back160);

    federal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent reserve = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), parliamonar.class);
            startActivity(reserve);

        }
    });

    federal = findViewById(R.id.next164);

    federal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent reserve = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), sar.class);
            startActivity(reserve);
        }


    });



}

public void Onclick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(federalparliamentary.this, politicalsystem.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Activity 1 is "politicalsystem".
I added with @Override method, but it says that I have to remove the method, so I added outside, then it says that I have to extract interface, so clicked on it, then it gave me a bunch of list. So I chose onClick(v:View ):void, but it still didn't solve the issue. I tried in another way without @Override, but nothing changed when I tested my app. I also tried inside onCreate method which did not modified the navigation as I desired.